# Drivers for older GPUs

Tags: ati, radeon

Hello I want a old driver for ATI Radeon 4550. This card can run smoothly Ubuntu? I'm new to Ubuntu and I want a driver for it.

My specs are:

- CPU: Intel core2 duo e6600 2.4 GHz dual core
- Ram: 4 GB
- GPU: ATI Radeon 4550 older but powerful for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to stick with the already installed open source radeon driver.
AMD Catalyst does only support graphics chips as of Radeon HD 5000.
But that is no problem because Ubuntu runs great with radeon driver!

Comment: but what can i do? i want to play some games and i need drivers for my card..  #%#k! ..

Comment: You can't do much about this - playing modern games with your "little bit dated hardware" wouldn't be convenient anyway. So try to live with the radeon driver, it's not that bad ...

Answer (score 0):

The open source drivers provided by the repository should work without a problem.

If you are new to Linux it can be a hassle to install the proprietary ATI drivers, as it requires you to do all the work from inside the terminal. I have also had problems where the ATI drivers caused problems with the X Window Server, whereas the open source drivers worked like a charm. I have an R7 290x using the open source drivers on my desktop computer (Debian 8) and it is able to run the Cinnamon desktop environment without an issue. It also worked fine out of the box with Ubuntu 14.04.

If you are looking to play games on Linux, I don't see any reason why you should be worried about getting the ATI official drivers. An older card like the 4550 can handle the Unity desktop environment and some basic games. If you do not yet have the open source drivers from the repository, open a terminal window and type the following command:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

This will scan the repositories for the fglrx package and prompt you to accept the installation.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer : AMD Radeon HD 4000 series is not supported by fglrx (proprietary AMD code) ! Latest edition supported : fglrx in ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Yikes, sorry about that slip. Can't he use basic VESA drivers? Though I wouldn't want to try playing graphically intensive games on them.